# Use spaces in smbclient mkdir

Tags: shell-script, smbclient

I'm trying to use smbclient in a bash script to make a directory on a remote windows server.

Whilst this works:

```
smbclient -U "DOMAIN/$username" "//remoteserver/folder with spaces" --directory "Another folder with spaces/" -c "mkdir /newfolder/"
```

This doesn't:

```
smbclient -U "DOMAIN/$username" "//remoteserver/folder with spaces" --directory "Another folder with spaces/" -c "mkdir /folder to create with spaces/"
```

Instead a folder simply called 'folder' is created.
I've tried many variations like the following:

```
"mkdir /folder\ to\ create\ with\ spaces/"
"mkdir '/folder to create with spaces/'"
'mkdir '/folder to create with spaces/''
```

but can't seem to find the magic combination.

Comment: The escape char isn't /, it is \. So give `mkdir '/folder\ to\ create\ with\ spaces'` a try.

Comment: Apologies - mistake in my question write up - I did try \ not / - question updated.

Comment: What is the difference supposed to be between the 2nd and the 4th?  (-:

Comment: Ooops! :) edited

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These options should work:

- `-c 'mkdir "folder to create with spaces"'`
- `-c "mkdir \"folder to create with spaces\""`

Comment: How do you escape a `"` in a filename, I didn't find how to do it...